# How to typeset a file path?

Tags: best-practices

I would like to properly typeset a file path, e.g.

```
C:\Program Files\Some program\bin\executable.exe
```

The first problem I encountered was that LaTeX tries to treat `\Program` as a command. I tried escaping it with another backslash which created a linebreak.

Then I found this package [menukeys](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/menukeys) but I am not really happy because it typesets system-specific delimiters (i.e. `\` for Windows and `/` for Unix-like) as some weird arrows.

Which leads to my question: what is the preferred way of typesetting a file path in LaTeX?

Comment: @Mico Oh, thanks, did it like in the [wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks#Local_file). Did not occur to me at firt that `url` will be the responsible package but now it works. You still have to escape the \ though.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write `\url{C:\Program Files\Some program\bin\executable.exe}`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You could load the package `url` with the option `obeyspaces` and encase the fully qualified file name in a `\url` instruction:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[obeyspaces]{url}
\begin{document}
\path{C:\Program Files\Some program\bin\executable.exe} % equivalent to \url{...}, but more semantic
\end{document}
```

*Addendum*: If you need or wish to allow line breaks at the spaces, choose the `spaces` option as well:

```
\usepackage[obeyspaces,spaces]{url}
```

Comment: Package `url` also defines the command `\path{<some\thing>}`. It is doing just the same, but it seems semantically better.

Comment: @Masi - The `Option clash ...` message means that the `url` package has already been loaded, but without either the `spaces` or the `obeyspaces` option. Check your preamble and the packages that are loaded by your preamble.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I got confused by another problem, which I opened here http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/267061/13173 Running your command in MacTeX 2015 gives apparently wrong output.

Comment: @Johannes_B - The `\path` macro may indeed seem "semantically better", at first. However, it's not entirely identical to `\url`: If the `hyperref` package is loaded, using `\url` will create a hyperlink, whereas using `\path` does not.

Comment: Lack of a hyperlink to on a path might be desirable, if the path is just a description of what's available on a remote server (i.e. the link wouldn't work if you clicked it).

Comment: @EL_DON - Indeed, it’s the pointlessness of providing a URL to a nonaccessible place on someone’s hard disk that explains best why the output value of `\path` is not made into a URL.

Answer (score 14):

I'm quite fond of `menukeys`, and I think you should still consider using it.

Unfortunately, `menukeys` currently doesn't provide its users a way of customising the *output* path separator (the "weird arrow" you're referring to). However, I'm sure [Tobias "Tobi" Weh](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4918/tobi) (the author of `menukeys`) would add that feature in a future release if he sees this question.

In the meantime, here is a way of customising the path separator.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{menukeys}

\makeatletter

% --- macro for changing path sep ---
\newcommand\setnewpathsep[1]
{%
    \tw@declare@style@simple*{paths}{%
       {\ttfamily\CurrentMenuElement}%
    }[%
       #1%
    ]{blacknwhite}
}

% --- reset the path separator (macro expands to original style def) ---
\newcommand\resetpathsep
{%
     \tw@declare@style@simple*{paths}{%
       {\ttfamily\CurrentMenuElement}%
    }[%
       \hspace{0.2em plus 0.1em}%
       \raisebox{0.08ex}{%
          \tikz{\fill[\usemenucolor{txt}] (0,0) -- (0.5ex,0.5ex)%
                    -- (0,1ex) -- cycle;}%
    }%
       \hspace{0.2em plus 0.1em}%
    ]{blacknwhite}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
% original style
\directory{C:/Program Files/Some program/bin/executable.exe}

% Windows style
\setnewpathsep{\textbackslash}
\directory{C:/Program Files/Some program/bin/executable.exe}

% Unix style
\setnewpathsep{/}
\directory{C:/Program Files/Some program/bin/executable.exe}

% back to original style
\resetpathsep
\directory{C:/Program Files/Some program/bin/executable.exe}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a way to change the output sep, but it’s not the good documented ;-) so thanks for your answer so far. I plan a new version, since the user interface isn't that good an the manual neither … but I can't tell when :-/

Comment: @Tobi No problem. Looking forward to the next release, but no pressure...

Comment: :-) You may like to follow on [GitHub](https://github.com/tweh/menukeys), I think I need some Beta-Testers ;-) An there you can add feature request too …

Comment: @Tobi I'll do that.

Comment: You can even use backslashes in your path (copy-paste path) with the `bslash` option like so:
`\directory[bslash]{X:\DIR\SUBDIR}`.

Unfortunately, your `\setnewpathsep{\textbackslash}` command removes line-breaks :-\

You'll need to change your makro to something like this:
   ` \makeatletter
     % --- macro for changing path sep ---
     \newcommand\setnewpathsep[1]
     {%
     \tw@declare@style@simple*{paths}{%
        {\ttfamily\CurrentMenuElement}%
     }[%
        \hspace{0.1em plus 0.1em}%
      #1
        \hspace{0.1em plus 0.1em}%
     ]{blacknwhite}
     }
    \makeatother`

Comment: This isn't a good solution as text won't wrap at newline anymore as it does in default `\directory{}`.