# Why typesetting file path not working?

Tags: urls, paths

I know this [How to typeset a file path?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/164446/13173) 
I think that the PATH command works like making possible to use shorter PATH in URLs. 
I have documents in my filesystem which I often include in my notes. 
I would like to assign their folder location by the path -command. 
However, I am not sure if I use the right function because of unexpected result below.

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[obeyspaces]{url}
\begin{document}

\path{/Users/masi/Dropbox/Internal Diseases}

\url{PubMed Central, Table 3_ Diabetes Care. 2010 Jan; 33(Suppl 1)_ S62–S69. doi_  10.pdf} 

\end{document}
```

Output:

```
/Users/masi/Dropbox/Internal Diseases

PubMed Central, Table 3_ Diabetes Care. 2010 Jan; 33(Suppl 1)_ S62–S69. doi_  10.pdf
```

Expected output:

```
/Users/masi/Dropbox/Internal Diseases/PubMed Central, Table 3_ Diabetes Care. 2010 Jan; 33(Suppl 1)_ S62–S69. doi_  10.pdf
```

### 2nd example having pseudocode

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[obeyspaces]{url}
\begin{document}

\somePathCommand{/Users/masi/Dropbox/Internal Diseases}

\someHrefCommand{PubMed Central, Table 3_ Diabetes Care. 2010 Jan; 33(Suppl 1)_ S62–S69. doi_  10.pdf}{Diabetes Guideline}

\end{document}
```

which should print the link [Diabetes Guideline](http://%20%20%20%20/Users/masi/Dropbox/Internal%20Diseases/PubMed%20Central,%20Table%203_%20Diabetes%20Care.%202010%20Jan;%2033(Suppl%201)_%20S62%E2%80%93S69.%20doi_%C2%A0%2010.pdf) i.e. having redirection to:

```
/Users/masi/Dropbox/Internal Diseases/PubMed Central, Table 3_ Diabetes Care. 2010 Jan; 33(Suppl 1)_ S62–S69. doi_  10.pdf
```

How can you typeset correctly the file path?
I.e. use it with images, and do not print the actual path in the document as text.

Comment: Sorry, I have not understood the question. Both the `\url` command as the `\path` command work as expected. What's wrong with the outcome of  `\path{/Users/masi/Dropbox/Internal Diseases}` in the image?

Comment: The question contains an [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HGeC1.png). The purpose of `\path` is to print the path and it does print it. What do you expect it to do otherwise? And what is the relation to `\url`?

Comment: What do you expect `\path{/Users/masi/Dropbox/Internal Diseases}` to do other than typesetting the argument?

Comment: What's wrong with `\path{/Users/masi/Dropbox/Internal Diseases/PubMed Central, Table 3_ Diabetes Care. 2010 Jan; 33(Suppl 1)_ S62–S69. doi_  10.pdf}` or `\url{/Users/masi/Dropbox/Internal Diseases/PubMed Central, Table 3_ Diabetes Care. 2010 Jan; 33(Suppl 1)_ S62–S69. doi_  10.pdf}`?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is pretty unclear; what do you mean by “use it with images, and do not print the actual path in the document as text”? You claim to want to print the path and then not to. This is contradictory.

Comment: @egreg Sorry for being confusing. I made the body now clearer. I think I am trying to something what is not expected by the command.

Comment: In your update, you write "I think that the PATH command works like making possible to use shorter PATH in URLs". That's not the case, unfortunately. The `\path` instruction is just an alias for `\url`.

Comment: @Mico Thank you for your confirmation! Any similar tool which can help me achieve what I want?

Comment: @Masi - Please see the answer I've posted in the meantime.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your objective. I can offer the following observations:

- The `url` package defines `\path` as an "alias" for `\url`. Using `\path` may be more mnemonic than using `\url` if the argument is the name of a "path" rather than an ordinary URL.
- There's one important difference, though, between `\url` and `\path`: If the `hyperref` package is loaded, the argument of a `\url` instruction will be made into a hyperlink, whereas that's not the case with `\path`.
- If the path/url is a long and unwieldy string, and if you wish to show just a short stub instead, be sure to load the `hyperref` package and to use that package's `\href` macro. This macro takes two arguments: (i) a URL-like string, and (ii) the "stub" that should be shown in the pdf file instead of the URL-like string.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[spaces,obeyspaces]{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % just for this example
\begin{document}
output of \verb+\path+:

\path{/Users/masi/Dropbox/Internal Diseases/PubMed Central, Table 3_ Diabetes Care. 2010 Jan; 33(Suppl 1)_ S62–S69. doi_  10.pdf}

\bigskip
output of \verb+\url+:

\url{/Users/masi/Dropbox/Internal Diseases/PubMed Central, Table 3_ Diabetes Care. 2010 Jan; 33(Suppl 1)_ S62–S69. doi_  10.pdf}

\bigskip
output of \verb+\href+:

\href{/Users/masi/Dropbox/Internal Diseases/PubMed Central, Table 3_ Diabetes Care. 2010 Jan; 33(Suppl 1)_ S62–S69. doi_  10.pdf}{stub}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The output of the stub is wanted but without typing the preceding path */Users/masi/Dropbox/Internal Diseases/* every time. Is that possible?

Comment: If you don't want to show the substring `/Users/masi/Dropbox/Internal Diseases/`, just omit it from the argument of `\url` or `\path`.

Comment: I must confess I don't understand why you would want to show a long and complicated filename instead of a suitable stub, such as "Diabetes Care, 2010". Why would anyone care to be shown the full filename?

Comment: I want to create a link to the path (complete link) but show just a stub. I do not want to write long PATHs to my notes.

Comment: @Masi - I guess I still am not getting what you're aiming to achieve. Shall I delete my answer? Please advise.

Comment: No. It is good. I completed the addition of the second example. Clearer?

Comment: I think he is looking for `href` to link to the paper. Oh, already in the answer. Maybe set a macro for the filepath to use in `href` (if possible).

Comment: @Johannes_B -- your guess is as good as mine. Please feel free to post a separate answer.